# Filler not updating properly

Tags: java, swing, validation, jscrollpane, repaint

So when I open my document, this is what I see:

[image]

Here are the first and the first part of the second page (the rest of it is empty) of my document. Except for the content in the green rectangle (which is managed by box layout), they are 100% equal.

After all visible elements (magenta stuff, the first JTextArea (bigger than the others) doesn't matter regarding to the problem), they both have a Box.Filler added to them, to push all the content to the top of the page.

So when I open the document item 38. should be as high as all others, but for some reason it isn't.

I did't call the repaint and validate on both JScrollPane and it's viewport that conatins both pages right after opening of a document.

Also, when I add or remove another element anywhere in the document, number 38 comes to it's senses and resizes to it's proper height. I did call the sam repaints and validates when that happens as I have at the opening of the document.

chageShape() method called on the filler with same sizes it had does the trick, but it seems to be a dirty solution...

But why doesn't it do that right away?

EDIT: After some more testing, I have discovered that the filler has been a bad bad boy here. But it's hard for me to understand why the one on the first page always updates itself properly (even with fewer elements on the page), but the one on second page refuses to, even though there are no differences in how the two pages were coded (two instances of the same object) and that repaint and validate is called from a container superior to both.

Comment: Hmmm... what is is? What's your problem and what's your code?

Comment: @StanislavL s/he want to formatting, scalling, etc current screen to iText,

Comment: It is difficult to understand the cause without knowing more about what types of components you have added, and what layouts are being used to arrange them.  Please show the code used to build the component before it gets added to the viewport.